# How to stop intent service that is launched in another process from activity

Tags: android, intentservice

I have made an Intent service and that is working as expected, And I know that intent service does it works and stop itself after its working , so there is not need to stop it. I have made my intent service as you can google it , but I have launched it in a separate process. the code goes like this in xml

```
android:process=":MYPROCESS"
```

so in my app , I launch the intent service in the following way on button click

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadService.ALARM_SERVICE);
    intent.setClass(this,DownloadService.class);

    /* Send optional extras to Download IntentService */
    intent.putExtra("url", "http://myurl.com");
    intent.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
    intent.putExtra("requestId", 101);

    startService(intent);
```

this is just to give you idea How I am starting it , its normal.

**What is Happening**

I have made a button to stop a service , my this service is downloading something. so What I did , I killed the process , but that start the service again .

As I wanted my service to start again when it is killed by the system or when app is killed so I have set intent to redeliver like following

```
setIntentRedelivery(true);
```

So it is amazing situation :so simplifying my question as following

I want to stop service to not to start again , but when it is killed by system or it is killed when user removes app from recent apps , then service should start again (which is going good).

Please tell me how can I achieve this .

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you'd have to further modify your custom `DownloadService` derived from `IntentService`.  The `IntentService` base class is automatically starting a thread and servicing your `Intent` there, shutting down the thread and the service when it has no more work to do.  You have 2 choices you could use to stop the service:

1. Implement `onStop()` in your service and have it set an internal (synchronized) `shutdown` boolean.  In your `onHandleIntent()` you could check for this flag and prematurely exit the handler and possibly call `stopSelf()` to prematurely exit.
2. Alternatively, you could add your own `onBind()` implementation and have your `Activity` bind with the service.  Then expose a binder method (see docs on AIDL) to be called by your `Activity` when you want to exit the service.  Like above, your service's `onHandleIntent()` would need to watch for this early-exit type flag and cause itself to stop prematurely.

Note that in either case the service's process will most likely not get killed and this is normal.  Android keeps processes cached and in a ready-to-go state so it is very responsive when new requests to start its components arrive.  This does *not* mean your service is "running".  It just means the process which will host the service is already created and ready to go.

Comment: can you describe your point number one a litle more, What boolean variable shoud I declare and to inspect what ?

Comment: It depends on your `onHandleIntent` implementation. If it is polling or doing work in a loop, you can add a your own boolean `shutdown`. If you don't use a loop, you'll need to either wait for it to finish and then check, or add some logic to interrupt the operation before checking.

Comment: I am thinking on implementing the Result receiver , i have implemented it , but I want to start the service from splash activity and want to make the mainactivity as a result receiving side. How can I set the main activity in this 

 mReceiver = new DownloadResultReceiver(new Handler());
            
            mReceiver.setReceiver(MainActivity.class); // but this line giving me the error. how can I set Mainactivity as a receiver in Splash activiyt ?

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to do, there's not enough code.

Comment: please read my this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752453/getting-the-current-status-of-process-service-anytime-the-activity-starts/33753023?noredirect=1#comment55275147_33753023